# Хороший пример GWT UiBinder.. где его найти?

Tags: gwt, java

Ссылочку пожалуйста и пример кода. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На официальном сайте GWT, там вообще можно найти всю необходимую [документацию](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) и [уроки с примерами](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/index.html). Конкретно по UIBinder вот урок с примерами: http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Answer (score 2):

Неплохой [пример](http://www.nieleyde.org/SkywayBlog/post.htm?postid=e49efd5b-31c8-423f-9fff-91c2ba6514ed) использования UIBinder для MVP-подхода.